# Make `Collection` protocol unique by Element property

Tags: ios, swift, generics

I have been trying to make this extension generic, without any success. Any ideas how to improve it? (I would like to get rid of the hardcoded `WKBackForwardListItem` and `url` part and just accept any property) But I am afraid this is not possible just yet?

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element: WKBackForwardListItem {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        var seen: [Iterator.Element] = []

        for element in self {
            if seen.map({ $0.url }).contains(element.url) == false {
                seen.append(element)
            }
        }

        return seen
    }
}
```

Ideally the signature will end up like this

```
func unique(by property: Property) -> [Iterator.Element] {
```

**Update**

Given the nature of the array, an WKWebView history. It is very important to preserve the order of the array. So every use of `Set` is out of the question.

**Update 2**

Resulting code was, I lost the `Collection` protocol, but that is ok for this example.

```
extension Array where Iterator.Element: Equatable, Iterator.Element: Hashable {
    func unique() -> [Iterator.Element] {
        return NSOrderedSet(array: self).array as! [Iterator.Element]
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Since you depend on a property, you need to specify the element type using `where`. As an aside, simply loading data into a `Set` and using `contains` is more efficient than your code which O(n2)

Comment: What is this function supposed to do exactly? I don't think I understand the desired output. Specifically, `seen.map({ $0.url })` doesn't quite make sense. How is `seen` ever populated? Or is `seen.map` just supposed to return an empty array every time?

Comment: Pass a *closure* (which maps a collection element to the property) as an argument to the method.

Comment: Sadly `Set` is not an option. It doesn't preserve the order of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `NSOrderedSet` (and `NSMutableOrderedSet`). It has the uniqueness of `Set` with the ordering of `Array`! [See Apple's documentation.](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsorderedset)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create this extension of `Collection`. What you need is a `Set`. The only thing you need to make sure is that the items in your array conform to the `Equatable` protocol.

Sample:

```
let food = ["taco", "apple", "pizza", "taco"]
let uniqueFood = Set(food) // ["taco", "apple", "hot dog"]
```

Then all you need to do is create an `Array` from that `Set`:

```
let foodArray = Array()
```

For your use case `WKBackForwardListItem` does conform to `Equatable` so you won't need to do anything special for that.

In order to maintain the order of your data Apple has provided `NSOrderedSet`. This has the uniqueness that `Set` offers while maintaining the order `Array` provides.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use `Set` because I need to preserve the order of the array :(

Comment: You're looking for `NSOrderedSet` then like andyvn22 mentioned.